# React with ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs, react-redux, asp.net-core-2.0

Is there a way to setup webpack in reactredux SPA template provided by Microsoft for dotnet core 2 to write react with js/jsx instead of typescript. I would like to avoid using typescript if possible :) any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've found that it's easier to start with the ASP.NET Core 2 Redux template, change all .ts / .tsx files to .js / .jsx, modify the code accordingly, then add Redux yourself

Comment: I've tried that and it's not working. I change tsx to js and all code inside components and routes, but it wont compile. Do i need to change something inside webpack? I am really just a basic user of webpack, and don't know how to configure it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar if this was implemented in vs2017 updates because i have used vscode for react-redux apps. But with [VS2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) (release date 02.04.2019) react and react-redux templates for SPA are using javascript. That's all i wanted, so i will close this question.